# What's the relationship or logic this sentence indicates?

Tags: meaning, sentence

> Then, late last year, other scientists began reporting failures replicating Mr. Han’s results. Facing mounting pressure, he and his co-authors finally retracted the paper, though they have since vowed to clear their names. ([source](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/10/13/world/asia/china-science-fraud-scandals.html))

I felt quite confused upon reading this paragraph. There are mainly two problems. What should we know from this piece of text, they vowed to clear their names before they retracted the paper, or after that? What does "since" refers to, since they retracted the paper, or since other scientists began reporting failures?

Comment: I think we can agree that the relationship and logic is a mess. It seems likely this became stranded after an edit.

Answer (score 1):

'Though' is a conjunctive adverb which, as an adverb, modifies the verb preceding it - 'retracted' - and, as conjunctive, then connects the following clause to the whole sentence, the clause being 'they have since vowed to clear their names'.

The clause is connected by the word 'though', which also modifies the verb 'retracted'.

So the vow came 'since' or after the retraction.

Comment: But "though" indicates transition, doesn't it?  Which caused me to feel they cleared names before they retracted the paper.